# Call Jquery Server side asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

i want to use [this](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-notify/) plugin on my asp.net application.
I am serializing my title and text serverside with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class.
and i have no problem to show it.
but my challenge is :
i am loading titles and Contents of notifies from database.
i have no problem with load and selecting from Database.
i want to refresh notifies on every page load for user.
for example 4 row added to Notification Table on database.
how can i serialize 4 valuable and binding it to Source and title property of JQUERY notification plugin and displaying 4 notifier to user dynamically ? 
for 1 valuable that i want to bind to a jquery property plugin i am using this code snippet:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string jsArray = serializer.Serialize(my public Variable that is binded to Jquery plugin);
```

i am binding public c# valuable to jquery plugin in this type :

```
  title : <%=C# Variable%>
```

how can i use this method to displaying notifiers to user dynamically?
is there any better method?
i want to show notifies on all pages. have i to put codes on Basepage?
English Is not my frist language . Does my question Clear? thanks all

For example i have 4 new notification in database i am loading them in memory how can i displaying them as notification to user. i said i have no problem to display one my problem to display them dynamically depend on my updates on database on each page load. thanks all

Comment: English Is not my frist language .
Does my question Clear?
thanks all,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just have to add a new notify script entry for each entry from your database on page load.  This is very basic and you should just replace the hardcoded ID / css classses

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


    <script runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string notifyScript = "$(\"#container\").notify();$(\"#container\").notify(\"create\", \"basic-template\", { title: '{0}', text: '{1}'},{ expires: false, speed: 1000 });"
           Dictionary<string,string> notifications = your titles/text from DB;
           foreach(KeyValuePair notification in notifications)
           {
                notificationScript.Text += String.Format(notifyScript, notification.Key, notification.Value);
           }
        }
    </script>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <link href="test.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.notify.js"></script>
        <title>Show a notify box</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                        <asp:Literal ID="notificationScript" runat="server" />
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="default"></div>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="basic-template">
                    <a class="ui-notify-cross ui-notify-close" href="#">x</a>
                    <h1>#{title}</h1>
                    <p>#{text}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hmm... For example i have 4 new notification in database i am loading them in memory how can i displaying them as notification to user.
i said i have no problem to display one my problem to display them dynamically depend on my updates on database on each page load.
thanks all.